# Given an array of integers check whether there are two numbers present with given product

Tags: java

http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=667
You can find Qusetion on above link .Why it is not showing me the required output. Infact I am just putting value of N which is array size, P = required output arrays values in array but after taking all values it is not showing any result.

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        int P = in.nextInt();

        for(int i =0 ; i<=N ; i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int j=0 ; j<arr.length;j++){
            for(int k = j+1;k>=j;++k){
                if(arr[j]*arr[k]==P){
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Run Time Error
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>   at GFG.main(File.java:14)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this for loop

```
for(int k = j+1;k<=j;++k)
```

you should have this:

```
for(int k = j+1;k< arr.length;++k)
```

in your version you start `k` from `j+1` which is by definition larger that `j` hence you never get to the inside of that loop.

And also this line:

```
for(int i =0 ; i<=N ; i++)
```

Should be this:

```
for(int i =0 ; i< N ; i++)
```

That's because you are creating an array of size `N` but setting its values for `N+1` times.

Comment: First of all really thanks for helping Sir.I tried your solution but it didn't work out.

Comment: This solution points to a problem, but doesn't fix the actual Java error. Not running a `for` loop doesn't cause a runtime error.

Comment: Right, your first loop also has an issue. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for(int k = j+1;k<=j;++k){

if J is 10, then K starts at 11 which automatically breaks the condition K <=J, and the inner loop never runs.

Comment: This will not cause `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: What inputs are you providing when you run the program?

Answer (score 0):

Your runtime error is being thrown by the Scanner. Sometimes a Java Scanner can pick up a newline character, which throws a runtime exception. Try using a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html): `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Also, hen you are filling the array, remember that arrays go from index 0, to `array.length-1`. When you create an array like: `int[] arr = new int[N];`, you get a new `int` array of N indices. Because the first index is at 0, the final index is at `N-1`. Therefore, in the `for` loop when `k = N`, the index `arr[i]` is 1 greater than the largest index. Using `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){...}` will prevent that.